# URLs as parameters in MTM/TFS automated coded UI tests

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

Using MTM I record a test on a client site, then create an automated coded UI tests.  I want to run the same test on several client sites which have the same user interface.  Is is possible to pass in a different URL and otherwise reuse the codedUI test or is it neccessary to make a recording of each test on each different URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Data Driven tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx). This way in your test case you can supply as many URLs as you like *(per row, so each is a separate iteration)* and the test will run one time for each URL. You will need to add a DataSource to the attributes in your `[TestMethod]`. The link should help you set this up.

EDIT:
There are also alternative DataSource's you can use, but I assume MTM is your preference.